# Return ENUM(defined in one class) from member function of other class

Tags: c++, enums

I have this code

```
#include <iostream>
class A;

using namespace std;


class C {
    A::B fun(){
    }
};

class A{
    public:
    enum B {b1};
};


int main()
{

}
```

This code gives me an error `main.cpp:8:5: error: ‘B’ in ‘class A’ does not name a type`.

Does anyone know how to return `A::B` without moving `A` to top?

Comment: Why not define the `enum` out of class `A` as a new type of data use `typedef` and declare a member variable of this type in class `A`.

Comment: Cannot change the already defined code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q** Does anyone know how to return A::B without moving A to top?

**A** That is not possible.

Forward declaration of `A` does not give any details of what's inside the `A`. Hence, `A::B` is not a known type in `class C`.

In order to use `A::B` in `class C`, you have to put the complete definition of `class A` before the definition of `class C` starts.